# Why 'reduced to poverty' is same with 'become poor'?

Tags: phrase-meaning

The explanation in my English book is

> when a man is reduced to poverty the beggar will come out

I don't know why 'reduced to poverty' means 'become poor'.  Is it idiomatic expression? Or can anyone explain in grammar?

Comment: You could think of it as: "reduced (in wealth) to poverty"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the phrase is idiomatic. Consider these examples of the verb "reduce":

> To bring to a humbler, weaker, difficult, or forced state or condition; especially:
>
> a. To gain control of; subject or conquer: “a design to reduce them under absolute despotism” (Declaration of Independence).
>
> b. To subject to destruction: Enemy bombers reduced the city to rubble.
>
> c. To bring to a specified undesirable state, as of weakness or helplessness: disease that reduced the patient to emaciation; teasing that reduced the child to tears.
>
> d. To compel to desperate acts: The Depression reduced many to begging on street corners.
>
> e. To lower in rank or grade; demote.

Read more at http://www.yourdictionary.com/reduce#WhrjwE1BGIPuUrYu.99

Comment: thank you haha. I understood completely as it is idiomatic